# Getting Strings from A Cursor in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

My cose is SIMPLE.
I have a SQLite-Database with ***three columns***:

1. rowid
2. title => text
3. content => text

This is a method in my `dataBase`-class:

```
public Cursor fetchMessage(String tableNane, int id) {
    return myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT rowid as _id, title FROM "+tableName
    +" WHERE rowid = "+id, null);
}
```

This method will return only one row.

In my activity I wrote this:

```
Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.fetchMessage(tableName, id);
```

Now, I want to store the content field's text in a String.

How can this be done?

Comment: Don't write with caps lock. It's like shouting around.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use this:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("content"));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

First you'll want to move the Cursor you got from your Query to the first row using the [`moveToFirst()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29)-method.

After that you can get your fields values by using the [`getString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29) or [`getInt()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt%28int%29)-methods.